# Using map and filter function

Tags: haskell

I can't figure out how to implement the map and filter function for a matrix. Does anyone have any suggestions that would satisfy these tests?

```
-- | Matrix Tests
--
-- prop> mapMatrix (\a -> a - 3) (mapMatrix (+ 3) x) == x
--
-- >>> filterMatrix (< 3) matrix1
-- [[1,2],[2]]

-- >>> filterMatrix (> 80) []
-- []

-- >>> transpose' matrix2
-- [[1,4],[5,8]]


mapMatrix :: (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]
mapMatrix f [list] = [map f list]

filterMatrix :: (a -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
filterMatrix = undefined

transpose' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose' = undefined

matrix1 = [[1 .. 10], [2 .. 20]]

matrix2 = [[1, 5], [4, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some hints, but not a complete solution because this sounds like homework.  `mapmatrix` and `filterMatrix`: write functions that work on one row of your matrix at a time, then `map` those onto the list of rows.  `transpose'`: one way to do this would be with a list comprehension that applies the `!!` operator to lists of indices, and another would be a recursive function that removes one row at a time from the input and adds one column at a time to the output.

Is `filterMatrix` supposed to return a list of lists that is not a valid matrix?